# Stuck on how to approach integral $\int_0^1x^n\log(x)\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, definite-integrals

I am being asked the following:

For $n \gt 0$, and by considering an appropriate limit, find:

$$\int_0^1x^n\log(x)\,dx$$

I want to try integration by parts, but I am confused about what the question means when it states by considering an appropriate limit.

Comment: Integration by parts seems appropriate, and you will have to consider the limiting behaviour as $x$ approaches $0$ from above as $\log(0)$ is undefined.

Comment: A more general identity [β-function or Γ-function? $C\left( p,q\right) =\int _{0}^{1}x^{p}\left( \log x\right) ^{q}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3773385/%ce%b2-function-or-%ce%93-function-c-left-p-q-right-int-01xp-left-log-x-r/3773666#3773666).  This may be more useful to you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note $\int_0^1x^n\,dx= \frac1{n+1}$ and

$$ \int_0^1x^n\log xdx= \frac {d}{dn } \int_0^1x^n\,dx =-\frac1{(n+1)^2}$$

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this is Leibniz Rule, more informally known as Feynman's trick.

Answer (score 2):

When approaching limits using integration by parts, you need to ask yourself: "which parts of this integral will become simpler when I integrate or differentiate it?"
So let's have a look at
$$\int x^n \ln(x)\mathrm{d}x$$
Well, $x^n$ doesn't become much more complicated when you differentiate or integrate it. However, while $\ln(x)$ is difficult to integrate, its derivative is quite simple, namely, $1/x$. So we choose
$u=\ln(x)$, $\mathrm{d}v=x^n\mathrm{d}x$, and from this we conclude $\mathrm{d}u=\frac{1}{x}\mathrm{d}x$, $v=\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$. So,
$$\int x^n \ln(x)\mathrm{d}x=\int u\mathrm{d}v=uv-\int v\mathrm{d}u=\ln(x)\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}-\int \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} \frac{1}{x}\mathrm{d}x$$
$$=x^{n+1}\left(\frac{\ln(x)}{n+1}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\right)+C$$
In the limiting case of $n\to 0$ this gives the nice expression
$$\int \ln(x)\mathrm{d}x=x\ln(x)-x+C$$

**EDIT:**
This also shows that
$$\int_0^1 x^n \ln(x)\mathrm{d}x=1^{n+1}\left(\frac{\ln(1)}{n+1}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\right)=\frac{-1}{(n+1)^2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_0^1x^n\log(x)dx=\left[\log(x)\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\right]_0^1-\int_0^1\frac{x^n}{n+1}dx=-\left[\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)^2}\right]_0^1=-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$$

Comment: Could you please clarify how you eliminated log(x)?

Comment: $u(x)=\log(x),\text{and}\quad v^{'}(x)=x^n$ so by using integration by parte we have $\int_a^b u(x)v^{'}(x)dx=(u(x)v(x))_a^b-\int_0^1u^{'}(x)v(x)dx$  $\int_0^1x^n\log(x)dx=\left[\log(x)\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\right]_0^1-\int_0^1(\log(x))^{'}\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}dx=-\int_0^1(\frac{1}{x})\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}dx=-\int_0^1\frac{x^n}{n+1}dx$

Comment: @DavGRozNow it looks clear

Comment: Yes, a little clearer thank you but I don't understand how to eliminate this term: $[log(x)\frac{x^n+1}{n+1}]_0^1$ because $log(x)$ is undefined for $x = 0$, so would I take the limit as x tends to negative infinity?

Comment: $\left[\log(x)\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\right]_0^1=\left[\log(1)\frac{1}{n+1}-\log(0)\frac{0}{n+1}\right]=\left[0-\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\log(x)\right]=\left[0-0\right]=0$

Comment: Thank you, makes much more sense now! I took the limit as x tends to 0 and got the same solution now.

Comment: @DavGRoz you welcom.

Answer (score 1):

Using integration by parts:

Let $\displaystyle u=\ln(x) \Leftrightarrow u'=\frac{1}{x}$ and $\displaystyle v=\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\Leftrightarrow v'=x^n$
\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}&=\int_0^1 x^n\ln(x)\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac{x^n\ln(x)}{n+1}\bigg\vert_0^1-\int_0^1\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)x}\mathrm{d}x\\
&=-\int_0^1\frac{x^n}{n+1}\mathrm{d}x\\
&=-\frac{1}{n+1}\bigg(\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\bigg\vert_0^1\bigg)\\
&=-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}
\end{align}
Hence our final answer is:
$$\mathcal{I}=-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$$
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=e^u$ and $dx=e^udu$

Then,

$$\int_{0}^{1} {x^nlnxdx}=\int_{-\infty}^{0} {ue^{un}e^udu}$$
$$=\int_{-\infty}^{0}ue^{(n+1)u}du$$
$$=\bigg[{{(n+1)u-1}\over{(n+1)^2}} {e^{(n+1)u}} ] _{-\infty}^{0}$$
$$=-{1\over {(n+1)^2}}$$